# Attaching an email message to an appointment

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I can successfully use the code below to add an email to an appointment before saving it to my calendar. However, when I try to populate the email before it goes into the appointment, it is blank once the appointment is saved into outlook.

Is there a way for the email to be saved in the appointment with all the relevant information that I am feeding to it in `With olMail`? If so, how do I achieve that?

```
Private Sub calendarUpdate()

'puts an appointment and agenda into my outlook calendar
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olApt As AppointmentItem
Dim olMail As MailItem




Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olApt = olApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)



emailText = "<H3>Hi Engineer,<br></H3>" & _
            "Can you please fill in the agenda template below (marked red)  and send it back to me ASAP, I will reformat the email where necessary before sending it to the broker/client<br><br>." & _
            "Cheers"

With olMail
    .To = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 21)
    .Subject = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) & " " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3) & " Agenda Letter Review."
    .HTMLBody = emailText
End With


With olApt
    .AllDayEvent = True
    .Start = Label3.Caption
    .End = Label3.Caption
    .Subject = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 18)
    .Location = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4) & ", " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5) & ", " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6) & ", " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7) & " " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8)
    .Attachment.Add olMail
    .Categories = "EA to Schedule"
    .ReminderSet = True
    .Save
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: I figured it out, I don't understand why it works and the above didn't, but that doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

I added `Dim myCopiedMessage As Outlook.MailItem` then set that item to the following

```
Set myCopiedMessage = olMail.Copy
```

Then added that as an attachment. I have no idea why this worked and my other code didn't, but that is beside the point.

```
Private Sub calendarUpdate()

'puts a possible appointment into my outlook calendar
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olApt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim myCopiedMessage As Outlook.MailItem



Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olApt = olApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)



emailText = "<H3>Hi Engineer,<br></H3>" & _
                "Can you please fill in the agenda template below (marked red) and send it back to me ASAP, I will reformat the email where necessary before sending it to the broker/client<br><br>." & _
                "Cheers"

With olMail
    .To = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 21)
    .Subject = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) & " " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3) & " Agenda Letter Review."
    .HTMLBody = emailText
End With

Set myCopiedMessage = olMail.Copy

With olApt
    .AllDayEvent = True
    .Start = Label3.Caption
    .End = Label3.Caption
    .Subject = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 18)
    .Location = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4) & ", " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5) & ", " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6) & ", " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7) & " " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8)
    .attachMents.Add myCopiedMessage, 1
    .Categories = "EA to Schedule"
    .ReminderSet = True
    .Save
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: If this was the answer, would you please click the tick symbol to the left, to mark the question as resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Save the message first:

```
olMail.Save
.Attachment.Add olMail
olMail.Delete
```